# How to check if file exists after serialization - C#?

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, filestream, binaryformatter

I use this function to save my game state into file with serialization:

```
public void SaveForX86 ()
{
    UpdateGameState();
    try
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        FileStream fs = File.Create(Application.persistentDataPath + Helper.GAME_DATA_FILE_NAME);

        GameData data = new GameData();
        data.experience = experience;
        data.score = score;
        data.winPercent = winPercent;
        data.tasksSolved = tasksSolved;
        data.correct = correct;
        data.additions = additions;
        data.subtractions = subtractions;
        data.multiplications = multiplications;
        data.divisions = divisions;
        data.useAddition = useAddition;
        data.useSubtraction = useSubtraction;
        data.useMultiplication = useMultiplication;
        data.useDivision = useDivision;
        data.minRange = minRange;
        data.maxRange = maxRange;
        data.longestChain = longestChain;
        data.useIncrementalRange = useIncrementalRange;
        data.gameStateDirty = gameStateDirty;
        data.longestTaskInSeconds = longestTaskInSeconds;
        data.overallTimeInSeconds = overallTimeInSeconds;
        data.operandsSign = operandsSign;
        data.difficulty = difficulty;

        bf.Serialize(fs, data);
        fs.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.Log(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I would like to check whether the file was created. How can I do that in this case?

Comment: So I leave the question as it is or delete it?

Comment: You can´t delete it as you have answers.

Comment: @vlad please click delete to save a lot of time for moderators. i gave you the full answer in the dupe question you made.

Comment: I can't, it has answers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
if (File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + Helper.GAME_DATA_FILE_NAME))
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don´t need to as if serialization fails (e.g. because of an IO-error) an exception should be thrown. So if none is thrown your file should have been created.